# Per branch `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a repo with several branches, each of which build in fairly similar process, and I need to deploy each of the branches to different locations (with different keys). What should be the best way to do this?

My current approach is a separate `branches:` section for each branch, but I need to have `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` in [each branch](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/branch-workflows-856697482.html):

> The same bitbucket-pipelines.yml file lives in the root directory of each branch.

Keeping 'the same' `.yml` in each branch seems cumbersome - I'd need to update several completely unrelated branches, when I'd like to change the build/deploy of my current branch. Currently i believe the best way is to keep only the section referring to current branch in that branch - but the official documentation is very unclear about how things interact.

It would probably make sense to me to keep only a single `.yml` somewhere in the default branch, but it does not build on push as of now.